# VS 2019 Go To Definition not working in XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

Hi last months I upgraded Visual Studio 2019 and I'm experimenting some problems like freezing and crashing  but the most annoying for me is this.

When I start Visual Studio and use *"Go To Definition"* in XAML for first time it works
[image]

[image]

But the next times I use *"Go To Definition"* it send me to the **System.Windows.Data.Binding** class

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this or downgrade to a stable version of Visual Studio?

I have done the next things :

- Delete .vs folder
- Restore Nuget Packages
- Reinstalled Visual Studio
- Installed VS in another computer

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem and it drives me crazy.

Comment: I think i was the only one :o ,
I didn't found a solution but now I'm working with  [Visual Studio 2019 Preview - Comunity](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)   and the problem seems to be gone, but there are still other bugs like debug icons disappear or visual studio freezing

Comment: Could you give more details about "debug icons disappear" for me to reproduce your error?